# Anauglar2 sub module to use module which is imported in root module

Tags: angular, typescript

Am trying to understand angular2 modules,

 In my application the modules became large one, so i planned to separate it out by different `sub-modules` and then connect with `root module`.

So i imported all common dependency modules of my `sub-modules` into `root-module` itself. but when i compile the application getting error `can't find module`.

**Child-Module (TransactionModule)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { RWTxnTotalsComponent } from './txn.totals.component';
import { RWTxnBillInfoComponent } from './txn.billinfo.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule],
    exports: [
        RWTxnTotalsComponent, // my component
        RWTxnBillInfoComponent // my component, It used  PanelModule inside of it templates.
        ],
    declarations: [
        RWTxnTotalsComponent,
        RWTxnBillInfoComponent
        ],
    providers: [],
})
export class TransactionModule { }
```

**Root-module(AppModule)**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing, routedComponents } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RootComponent } from './root.component';

import {DataTableModule,SharedModule, DropdownModule,AutoCompleteModule, GrowlModule, DialogModule, ButtonModule, CalendarModule, CheckboxModule, PanelModule, FieldsetModule, TooltipModule, TabViewModule,  InputMaskModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

//my-modules
import {TransactionModule}  from '../app/transaction/transaction.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   RootComponent, AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    OverlayPanelModule,
    GrowlModule,
    DialogModule,
    ButtonModule,
    DataTableModule,
    SharedModule,
    DropdownModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    CalendarModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    PanelModule, // This module is used in RWTxnBillInfoComponent sub module's template
    FieldsetModule,
    TooltipModule,
    TransactionModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here i imported the `PanelModule` in `root-module` itself and i can't use that in my `Child-module`. 
If i add the same `PanelModule` in `child-module` then it works but it seems multiple import.
Can anyone correct me to the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the "PanelModule" component and service in "TransactionModule" then you have to import it in "TransactionModule".

And its ok, if you are import one module in different other modules...

Also you need to exports the component and services which you want to use in other modules...

Comment: Dose it not cause duplication of `PanelModule` if i import the panel module in other different modules as well ?

Comment: How the angular2 avoids duplication while preparing the packages for production ?

Comment: No it will be not, always there will be single copy of each module its just dependency injection, like in angular one we do for created module...

Comment: Great.. well am surprised with angular2 packaging :-)